# MongoDB - bulk updating values in arrays of nested objects

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, migration, compass

I have a collection in MongoDB that represents the chores kids needs to do each day and whether they are done. Here is an example of a document.

```json
{
  "_id":"2022-02-13:joe",
  "kidName":"Joe",
  "chores": [
    {"chore":"Breakfast: clear dishes and utensils","done":true}, 
    {"chore":"Clearing dishes after meals","done":true},
    {"chore":"Put away coats, knapsack, and shoes","done":true}, 
    {"chore":"Clear toys","done":true}
   ],
    "date": 2022-02-13T00:00:00.000+00:00
  }
```

I want to change it so that, instead of a Boolean, `done` is an integer, where:

| Meaning | value |
| --- | --- |
| Done | 1 |
| Not Done | -1 |
| Unmarked | 0 |

Is there a pipeline or trick in Compass to do this for all documents in the collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [update method with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) to update the chores array. You would need to use the following pipeline to achieve the desired results:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
    { 'chores.0': { '$exists': true } },
    [
        { '$set': {
            'chores': {
                '$map': {
                    'input': '$chores',
                    'as': 'chore',
                    'in': {
                        '$mergeObjects': [
                            '$$chore',
                            { 
                                'done': {
                                    '$switch': {
                                        'branches': [
                                            { 'case': { $eq: [ '$$chore.done', true ] }, then: 1 },
                                            { 'case': { 
                                                $eq: [ 
                                                    { $ifNull: ['$$chore.done', 'Unmarked'] }, 
                                                    'Unmarked' 
                                                ] }, 
                                                then: 0 
                                            },
                                            { 'case': { $eq: [ '$$chore.done', false ] }, then: -1 },
                                        ],
                                        default: 0
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            } 
        } }
    ]
)
```